# Play 2.2 production mode logging on Heroku

Tags: logging, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.2

I've deployed a Play 2.2 application on Heroku.  Currently, the messages written to my loggers in my app are not appearing in the Heroku log, as the Play app is (apparently) writing to something other than stdout.

In development mode, my loggers are working fine (they write to stdout).  I would like my application to write its logging to stdout in production mode as well, so it ends up in Heroku's application log.

Is there a change I have to make in the configuration of Play to make this happen?

Comment: Have you read this? http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsLogger

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Got it working just moments before you posted this.  I will supply the details below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a file called `conf/application-logger.xml` in the application.  No other changes the `application.conf` were needed, and now the logging is working correctly on Heroku.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsLogger has these instructions.  However, my configuration differs from the example on that page in that I removed the appender to `FILE` and kept only the appender to `STDOUT` appender.

```
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
   <encoder>
      <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="application" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="mycustomlogger" level="INFO" />

  <!-- Off these ones as they are annoying, and anyway we manage configuration ourself -->
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />

  <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've started using Papertrail Heroku add-on https://addons.heroku.com/papertrail and pretty happy with it so far.